# Server push without GCM on Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently writing an Android app, and I would like to send push notifications from my server to the phones where this App will be running. Due to security reasons, I would like to avoid any third party server like Google's servers that are used when using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). How can I achieve that? Or do I need to use a workaround (e.g. polling or working with GCM and encrypting the messages)?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: try parse.com its fast, very easy to implement. It is a 3rd party but just it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to prevent Google from reading your messages is simply not sending any data to GCM. Use [send-to-sync-messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#send-to-sync) for that. To improve performance use [`collapse_key`](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages).

On receipt of a send-to-sync-message fetch the new data from your webservice. I also used this approach in a recent project with high security requirements.

Comment: @user3624130, how is this a solution. Is it not still using Google's server to send messages???

Comment: It is definitely was what I was looking for! You send a dummy message over Google's server that only tells the user "You have a new message, please send a HTTP(S) POST our own secure server to read this message". Then the client sends the POST and receives the message